# Null Pointer Exception when trying to send message from one activity to another

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, nullpointerexception

Why is there NullPointerException error when I try to implement the code which sends a string message from one activity to the BluetoothService Activity which extends Service.

Here is the main parts of the code that is involved in sending the string:

```
private BluetoothService mChatService = null;

public void onCaptureButtonClicked(View view) throws IOException{                                   
            try{
                    sendMessage("1");
                }catch(NullPointerException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            takePhoto(1);
        }
        }

private void sendMessage(String message) {

             if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
             return;
         }

         if (message.length() > 0) {
             byte[] send = message.getBytes();
             mChatService.write(send);
         }
     }
```

Here is the error logcat:

```
02-15 18:21:19.960: W/System.err(1252): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 18:21:19.960: W/System.err(1252):     at com.example.application.parss.CameraActivity.sendMessage(CameraActivity.java:751)
02-15 18:21:19.960: W/System.err(1252):     at com.example.application.parss.CameraActivity.onCaptureButtonClicked(CameraActivity.java:245)
02-15 18:21:19.960: W/System.err(1252):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 18:21:19.960: W/System.err(1252):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-15 18:21:19.960: W/System.err(1252):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2180)
02-15 18:21:19.960: W/System.err(1252):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2585)
02-15 18:21:19.960: W/System.err(1252):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9299)
02-15 18:21:19.960: W/System.err(1252):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-15 18:21:19.960: W/System.err(1252):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-15 18:21:19.960: W/System.err(1252):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-15 18:21:19.960: W/System.err(1252):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
02-15 18:21:19.960: W/System.err(1252):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 18:21:19.970: W/System.err(1252):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-15 18:21:19.970: W/System.err(1252):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
02-15 18:21:19.970: W/System.err(1252):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
02-15 18:21:19.970: W/System.err(1252):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT:

I intialised the mChatSession in this way:

```
 mChatService = new BluetoothService(this, mHandler);
```

And called this:
     mChatService.write(send);

But the similar NullPointerException error still persists.

Comment: How can an Activity extend Service?

Comment: Oh sorry I meant a class that extends Service.

Comment: which is the 751 number line in your code?

Comment: it is if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED) {.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting the exception because you haven't initialized `BluetoothService`.

```
private BluetoothService mChatService = null;
```

And you are using `mChatService.getState()` in your `sendMessage()` method without initializing.

Comment: I intialised BluetoothService but the same error still persist at mChatService.write();

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
     if(mChatService == null)
         return;
     if (message.length() > 0 && mChatService.getState() == BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
         byte[] send = message.getBytes();
         mChatService.write(send);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BluetoothService mChatService = new BluetoothService(args);
```

You need to assign an instance at some point to the variable.