# Null pointer exception while sending message

Tags: android, bluetooth, voice-recognition

I build android app voice recognition command to control devices over embedded bluetooth, i use example code BluetoothChat to send voice recognition result. but i got an error like this.

```
enter FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.embox.rumahpintar/com.embox.rumahpintar.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3378)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3421)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1311)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:756)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:572)
        at miui.dexspy.DexspyInstaller.main(DexspyInstaller.java:171)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.embox.rumahpintar.MainActivity.sendMessage(MainActivity.java:102)
        at com.embox.rumahpintar.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:89)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5324)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3374)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:148)
```

this is MainActivity class:

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "voice";
private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
private TextView speakInput;
ArrayList<String> result;
Button tapSpeak;

String perintah = "hidupkan lampu kamar";
BluetoothService mService = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        BluetoothFragment fragment = new BluetoothFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Smart Home @Created by Akmal Fadli", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    speakInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speakInput);
    tapSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tapSpeak);
    tapSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Speak recognition open....");
            promptSpeechInput();
        }
    });
}

public void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Receiving speech input
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                speakInput.setText(result.get(0));
                BluetoothFragment m = new BluetoothFragment();
                if (result.contains(perintah)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Perintah terkirim . . .", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   sendMessage(perintah);
                }
                break;
            }

        }

    }

}

private void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mService.getState() != BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mService.write(send);
    }
}
```

And this is SendMessage method:

```
 public void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mService.getState() != BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mService.write(send);
    }
}
```

give me advice please . . .

BluetoothService Class:

```
public class BluetoothService {
// Debugging
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatService";

// Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
private static final String NAME_INSECURE = "BluetoothChatInsecure";

// Unique UUID for this application
private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

//UUID uuid = device.getUuids()[0].getUuid();
//MY_UUID_SECURE = uuid;


// Member fields
private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
private final Handler mHandler;
private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;
private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private int mState;

// Constants that indicate the current connection state
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

/**
 * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
 *
 * @param context The UI Activity Context
 * @param handler A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
 */
public BluetoothService(Context context, Handler handler) {
    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    mHandler = handler;
}

/**
 * Set the current state of the chat connection
 *
 * @param state An integer defining the current connection state
 */
private synchronized void setState(int state) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
    mState = state;

    // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
    mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
}

/**
 * Return the current connection state.
 */
public synchronized int getState() {
    return mState;
}

/**
 * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
 * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
 */
public synchronized void start() {
    Log.d(TAG, "start");

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    setState(STATE_LISTEN);

    // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
    if (mSecureAcceptThread == null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(true);
        mSecureAcceptThread.start();
    }
    if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(false);
        mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
    }
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
 *
 * @param device The BluetoothDevice to connect
 *
 */
public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
    Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);
    mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
 *
 * @param socket The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
 * @param device The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
 */
public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice
        device) {
   // Log.d(TAG, "connected, Socket Type:" + socketType);

    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
    if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mSecureAcceptThread = null;
    }
    if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
    String konek = "Device connected...";
    byte[] pesan = konek.getBytes();
    mConnectedThread.write(pesan);

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}

/**
 * Stop all threads
 */
public synchronized void stop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "stop");

    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mSecureAcceptThread = null;
    }

    if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
    }
    setState(STATE_NONE);
}

/**
 * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
 *
 * @param out The bytes to write
 * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[]) (java.lang.String)
 */
public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionFailed() {
    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constants.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
   // BluetoothService.this.start();
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionLost() {
    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constants.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
    //BluetoothService.this.start();
}

/**
 * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
 * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
 * (or until cancelled).
 */
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
    private String mSocketType;

    public AcceptThread(boolean secure) {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {

                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                        NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_SECURE);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType +
                "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);

        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "accept() failed", e);
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type: " + mSocketType);

    }

    public void cancel() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "cancel " + this);
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "close() of server failed", e);
        }
    }
}


/**
 * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
 * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
 * succeeds or fails.
 */
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;


    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
       // mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
               tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                       MY_UUID_SECURE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {



        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception

                mmSocket.connect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " +
                        " socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            connectionFailed();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect " + " socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
 * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
//public class dulunya private
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
       // Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothService.this.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     *
     * @param buffer The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

SOLVED, I modified my code into one activity (MainActivity.class), so i moved BluetoothService into MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize kirimPesan so it has null value. So you have NullPointerException (exception that tells you that something is null).

You need to initialize kirimPesan with constructor before you able to send messages.

Alternatively you can put method sendMessage in your own class MainActivity, then you will not need kirimPesan object at all.

Comment: I have moved sendMesssage into MainActivity class but i still got the same error. :(

Comment: did you remove kirimPesan? In what line do you get an exception now.

Comment: yes sure, now my code just sendMessage(perintah); without kirimPesan.

Comment: And what is the exception text now?

Comment: still same, java.lang.NullPointerException. see my edited question to see BluetoothService.class. . .

Comment: I don't need your Bluetooth service, I need exact exception text and the latest code you have. You can probably update your question

Comment: i have updated, the errors is in line sendMessage(perintah); and mService.write(send);

Comment: Which line is line 102

Comment: mService.write(send);

Comment: So now mService is null because you didn't initialize it. You need to initialize it in onCreate

Comment: i already initialize mService but i still got an error, but myproblem solved now because i modified my app into  one activity. Another problem same like me [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796313/null-pointer-exception-when-trying-to-send-message-from-one-activity-to-another?rq=1) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790419/android-bluetoothchat-use-send-receive-methods-from-another-class?rq=1). Thank you very much, for your reply.